# Installing a washing machine standpipe with existing sink

Tags: plumbing

I have a bathroom sink on the 2nd story, plumbed and vented in the usual manner. I want to install a washing machine on the other side of the wall. Can I install the washing machine standpipe and tie it right into the drain on the sink, as though the sink were a utility sink? If I did that, would I need to change the venting at all?

Comment: You say the washing machine would be on the other side of the wall; to tie it "right into the drain on the sink" would necessitate running a pipe through the wall to the other side. Is this the case, and if so why would you not just open the wall and create a proper tie-in with a dedicated trap assembly?

Comment: I plan on opening the wall. I meant "do a proper trap that empties into the sink's post-trap pipe". I don't want to mess up the venting for the existing sink, and I would rather not put a new hole into the existing cast iron waste stack if I can tie into an existing pipe.